# How can I indent text in a text file containing special keywords without using arrays or any regex

Tags: java, indentation, pseudocode

My program has to indent the text from a text file every time the current line contains some specific keywords, withing using arrays or any regex.

exemple ;

```
start
write "enter your name
read name
write "enter your age"
read age
if age==100 then
do
print "you stink"
while age !=100
end if
while something
if something
do something
while something
end if
end
```

should be :

```
start

   write "enter your name"
   read name

   write "enter your age"
   read age

   if age==100 then
          do
          print "you stink"
          while age !=100
   end if
    while something
        if something
            do something
            while something
        end if
end
```

I can't get my program to correctly indent anything past the first 'keyword'. keywords being "while, if, do, end if, end, start, etc..."

I am not allowed to use arrays or any regular expressions

part of my code that reads the text file :

```
    String corrIndent (String pseudocode2) {
    String sTrim = ""; //pseudocode to return
    String sTmp;

    int debut = 0; //current line start index
    int fin; //current line end index

    fin = pseudocode2.indexOf("\n", debut);//read lines

    do {
         //extracts current line 
         sTmp = pseudocode2.substring(debut, fin);
         //opens the do..while loop indent level

         if(sTmp.contains("do")){//opens do indent(indents 1 level)

             for (int i=1;i<=999;i++){

                 sTmp =pseudocode2.substring(debut, fin);
                 //sTrim="\t";
                 if (sTmp.contains("while")){//close do indent (reduce indentation 1 level)
                    i=999;//supposes that the text file is never that long

                 } 
                 //add current line to string to return
                 //with a newline.
                 sTrim = sTrim + sTmp+ ""+"   ";
                 //ajuster le debut de la ligne courante suivante
                 debut =  fin + 1;
                 //trouver la fin de la ligne courante suivante
                 fin = pseudocode2.indexOf("\n", debut);
             }
         } 


         {//when no more indentation is needed
             sTrim = sTrim + sTmp + "\n";

             debut = fin + 1;

             fin = pseudocode2.indexOf("\n", debut);
         }

    }while (fin != -1);
    return sTrim;
  }
```

With this code, I can correctly indent the do block, but if another keyword is inside that do block, it will not get a new indent level.

Why is that?

I have tried numerous methods to get the indent level saved as a variable without success.

Comment: I am not allowed to use regex, so I can't the split method. What I'm trying to do is create a loop that ups the indent level every time a keyword is found, then reduce the indent level.    The same way brackets work in a normal code

Comment: *I have tried numerous methods to get the indent level saved as a variable* - where is this code?

Comment: `Split` will also split on non-regex, but the result is an array, which you are also not allowed to use.  By having a simple boolean `indent` variable declared before the loop should do the job.

Comment: Deleted, as I coudn't get anything to work.    For now, the for loop inside the if loop tells the indent level to go down, by not adding "   " anymore.

Comment: why not use indexOf and substrings methods?

Comment: I am to tired to do this tonight I will propose you a way tomorrow

Comment: Shouldn't the line `print "you stink"` be indented more, since it's the body of a `do..while` block? Also, are you required to handle malformed input, or can you assume everything is syntactically correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to use list ?

Comment: there is an issue on while

Comment: while did always add an lonely instruction or there is an end while ?

Comment: The text is incorrectly formatted, I trim the white spaces first, then use it code without any white spaces to start the indentation. I use indexOf and substring, but I cant seem to keep indenting once the indentation starts for 1 keyword, ex: DO.   I think its because Im unable to use the right index after ive started the first indent. Or something is wrong with my reading loop, but i cant find out what it is

Comment: You don't actually ever even look for other keywords...

Comment: I took it off the code exemple, but its just another if loop (if string.contains("if"). But it doesnt work. As if the first keyword that is found in the text is the only one to get indented. I could have many if loops, each with their own keyword, but they get skipped. A 'do' keyword will not start in indentation if it is between an 'if' and an 'end if' keyword.

Answer (score 2):

> **This solution uses both arrays and regex - I am posting here for future coders that may not have that restriction.**

Here is a quick sample I just whipped up. It lets you setup an array of words you want to indent and which words should trigger the indent to be decreased.

There is some room for improvement as it does not catch every case you may need.

You would also need to implement the writing of the output to file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String IN_FILE = "test.txt";
        final String OUT_FILE = "sample/indent/result.txt";
        final int INDENT_SPACES = 4;    // Number of spaces to indent

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int currentIndentLevel = 0;

        // Increase indent level on these keywords
        String[] keywordsIn = {"start", "if", "do"};

        // Decrease indent level on these keywords
        String[] keywordsOut = {"while", "end"};

        // Read the file, line by line
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(IN_FILE));

            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {

                // Indent the line based on current level
                for (int i = 0; i < INDENT_SPACES * currentIndentLevel; i++) {
                    output.append(" ");
                }
                output.append(line).append("\n");

                // Check if it contains a keyword
                for (int i = 0; i < keywordsIn.length; i++) {
                    // Line begins with a keyword to increase the indent
                    if (line.matches(keywordsIn[i] + "\\b.*")) {
                        currentIndentLevel += 1; // Increase the indent level
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < keywordsOut.length; i++) {
                    // Line begins with a keyword to decrease the indent
                    if (line.matches(keywordsOut[i] + "\\b.*")) {
                        currentIndentLevel -= 1; // Decrease the indent level
                    }
                }


                // Get next line
                line = reader.readLine();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

Taking your original input file, this is what this program outputs:

```
start
    write "enter your name
    read name
    write "enter your age"
    read age
    if age==100 then
        do
            print "you stink"
            while age !=100
        end if
    while something
if something
    do something
        while something
    end if
end
```

Comment: I will +1 you, but the last `if something` should be indented to the previous `while something`

Comment: I agree. I did not implement a way to differentiate between `do/while` and `while/do` so that's where it gets a little wonky.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but would you be able to code it WITHOUT arrays, tokens or regex?  I don't want to be given to answer, only a hint as to how to possibly code it. Im reading the text file line by line with indexOf, then if a substring contains a special word, it opens or closes an indent level. But only once and every other special word contained between are not correctly indenting.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a potentiel part of an answer i dont why noot use array and regex but why not

here is kind of code you need to implement but your language description is quite bad it is not LL(1) so you have issue to handle the differenc between an end and an end if ... an other issue is that you have no end delimiter for while instruction maybe and end while will help you ?

This kind of implementation is very heavy and ***I clearly not recommand that kind of things*** !! bu t it was funny to take the challenge ^^

```
public class MainIndent {

    public static enum Tokens {
        start("start", 1), end("end", -1), write("write", 0), end_if("end if", -1), read("read", 0), _if("if", 1),
        _do("do", 1), _while("while", 1);
        private final String keyword;
        private final int policy;

        Tokens(String keyword, int policy) {
            this.keyword = keyword;
            this.policy = policy;
        }

        public int getPolicy() {
            return policy;
        }

        public String getKeyword() {
            return keyword;
        }
    }

    public static String parse(String input, String indent) {
        String remaining = input;
        String parsed = "";
        int nbIndent = 0;
        int doCount = 0;
        while (!remaining.isEmpty()) {
            Tokens tokens = getNextToken(remaining);
            Tokens nextTokens = getNextToken(remaining.substring(tokens.getKeyword().length()));
            int indexOf;
            if (nextTokens == null) {
                parsed += createIndent(indent, nbIndent+tokens.getPolicy()) + remaining + "\n";
                remaining = "";
            } else {
                if (tokens == Tokens.end_if && (nextTokens == Tokens.end || nextTokens == Tokens.end_if)) {
                    indexOf = tokens.getKeyword().length()
                            + remaining.substring(tokens.getKeyword().length()).indexOf(nextTokens.getKeyword());
                } else {
                    indexOf = remaining.indexOf(nextTokens.getKeyword());
                }
                int lastIndent = nbIndent;
                if (tokens == Tokens._do) {
                    doCount++;
                    nbIndent++;
                } else if (tokens == Tokens._while && doCount > 0) {
                    doCount--;
                    nbIndent--;
                    lastIndent--;
                } else {
                    if (tokens.getPolicy() < 0) {
                        lastIndent--;
                    }
                    nbIndent += tokens.getPolicy();

                }
                parsed += createIndent(indent, lastIndent) + remaining.substring(0, indexOf) + "\n";
                remaining = remaining.substring(indexOf).trim();
            }
            System.out.println(parsed);
            System.out.println(remaining);
        }

        return parsed;
    }

    private static String createIndent(String indent, int nbIndent) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIndent; i++) {
            output += indent;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(corrIndent(
                "   start write \"enter your name\" read name\n write \"enter your age\" read age if age==100 then do write \"you stink\" while age!=100 end if while something if something do something while something end if end     "));
    }

    public static String corrIndent(String pseudocode2) {
        return corrIndent(pseudocode2, "    ");
    }

    public static String corrIndent(String pseudocode2, String indent) {
        String remainingStringtoParse = clearwhiteSpace(pseudocode2); // this will remove all current indentation
        return parse(remainingStringtoParse, indent);
    }

    private static Tokens getNextToken(String input2) {
        int startIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens.start.getKeyword());
        startIndex = startIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : startIndex;
        int writeIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens.write.getKeyword());
        writeIndex = writeIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : writeIndex;
        int readIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens.read.getKeyword());
        readIndex = readIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : readIndex;
        int ifIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens._if.getKeyword());
        ifIndex = ifIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : ifIndex;
        int doIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens._do.getKeyword());
        doIndex = doIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : doIndex;
        int whileIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens._while.getKeyword());
        whileIndex = whileIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : whileIndex;
        int endIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens.end.getKeyword());
        endIndex = endIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : endIndex;
        int endifIndex = input2.indexOf(Tokens.end_if.getKeyword());
        endifIndex = endifIndex == -1 ? input2.length() : endifIndex;
        if (startIndex < endIndex && startIndex < endifIndex && startIndex < writeIndex && startIndex < readIndex
                && startIndex < ifIndex && startIndex < doIndex && startIndex < whileIndex) {
            return Tokens.start;
        } else if (writeIndex < readIndex && writeIndex < ifIndex && writeIndex < doIndex && writeIndex < whileIndex
                && writeIndex < endIndex && writeIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens.write;
        } else if (readIndex < ifIndex && readIndex < doIndex && readIndex < whileIndex && readIndex < endIndex
                && readIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens.read;
        } else if (ifIndex < doIndex && ifIndex < whileIndex && ifIndex < endIndex && ifIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens._if;
        } else if (doIndex < whileIndex && doIndex < endIndex && doIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens._do;
        } else if (whileIndex < endIndex && whileIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens._while;
        } else if (endIndex < endifIndex) {
            return Tokens.end;
        } else if (endifIndex != input2.length()) {
            return Tokens.end_if;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String clearwhiteSpace(String pseudocode) {
        String remainingStringtoParse = pseudocode;
        String parsedString = "";
        while (remainingStringtoParse.length() > 0) {
            remainingStringtoParse = removeHeadWhiteSpace(remainingStringtoParse);
            int nextWhiteSpaceIndex = getNextWhiteSpaceIndex(remainingStringtoParse);
            parsedString += remainingStringtoParse.substring(0,
                    nextWhiteSpaceIndex == -1 ? remainingStringtoParse.length() : nextWhiteSpaceIndex)
                    + (nextWhiteSpaceIndex == -1 ? "" : " ");
            remainingStringtoParse = nextWhiteSpaceIndex == -1 ? ""
                    : remainingStringtoParse.substring(nextWhiteSpaceIndex);
        }
        return parsedString;
    }

    private static int getNextWhiteSpaceIndex(String remainingStringtoParse) {
        int whitespace = 0;
        while (remainingStringtoParse.length() > whitespace
                && !isWhiteSpace(remainingStringtoParse.charAt(whitespace))) {
            whitespace++;
        }
        return remainingStringtoParse.length() == whitespace ? -1 : whitespace;
    }

    private static String removeHeadWhiteSpace(String pseudocode) {
        int whitespace = 0;
        while (pseudocode.length() > whitespace && isWhiteSpace(pseudocode.charAt(whitespace))) {
            whitespace++;
        }
        return pseudocode.length() == whitespace ? "" : pseudocode.substring(whitespace);
    }

    private static boolean isWhiteSpace(char charAt) {
        return Character.isWhitespace(charAt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a tokenizer, an array or any regex. How can I keep looping reading the text file and indent it every time a line contains 'do, if, while, etc..' and de-indent when it contains 'end if, while, etc.' I have to indent it as if those words opened/closed { } brackets.

Comment: its an home work or something like ? if you can t defined rules for indent you can 't ... you speak now about bracket but wasn't in your questioon at the beggining... help me to understand why you torture your self like that  every one use tokeniser ( parser lexer like antlr, xText and many others) there is a reason...

Comment: Its homework, and those are the instructions (no token, no array, no regex).   La question du début parle d'indentation. Il s'agit d'indenter le texte lorsque le lecteur détecte certains mots clé, comme 'SI, FAIRE, TANT QUE'. C'est un fichier qui contient du pseudocode 'fonctionnel', mais mal indenté, comme s'il s'agissait d'un vrai programme, qui ouvre des braquettes/crochets lorsqu'on ecrit 'if, while, for' , etc.

Comment: stay in english please^^

Answer (score 0):

if you can't do it with arrays or regex, you're gonna have to use if statements.

You can do something like

```
$document = (openfile c:\test\document)
$indentVariable = 0
foreach $line in $document; do
    if $line starts with "if" OR "end if" OR "while" OR "end while";
        if $line starts with "if"
            $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
            indent $line $indentVariable tabs
            $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
        elseif $line starts with "end if"
            $indentVariable = $indentVariable - 2
            indent $line $indentVariable tabs
        elseif $line starts with "while"
            $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
            indent $line $indentVariable tabs
            $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
        elseif $line starts with "end while"
            indentVariable = $indentVariable - 2
            indent $line $indentVariable tabs
        end if
    else
        indent $line $indentVariable tabs
    end if
end foreach
```

you would need to add all types of words that indent further. this is why the solutions usually involve arrays etc...

This answer is based on "pseudocode" not anything at all java related.

also you could minimize it sort of like the first if statement. using a not real "array" on the if check
something like

```
$document = (openfile c:\test\document)
$indentVariable = 0
foreach $line in $document; do
    if $line starts with "if" OR "while"
        $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
        indent $line $indentVariable tabs
        $indentVariable = $indentVariable + 1
    elseif $line starts with "end if" OR "end while"
        $indentVariable = $indentVariable - 2
        indent $line $indentVariable tabs
    else
        indent $line $indentVariable tabs
    end if
end foreach
```